# Which SearchBar setting turns off tooltip menu?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I want to remove this black tooltip menu appearing when SearchBar is focused

[image]

my code for implementing this search bar in navigation view controller looks like this:

```swift
        let searchController = UISearchController()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = context.coordinator as? UISearchResultsUpdating
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator as? UISearchBarDelegate
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.definesPresentationContext = false
```